# List<JSONObject> vs JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

What is the difference between using `List<JSONObject>` and `JSONArray`?

This is the sort of structure I wish to loop through : `[{"key1","value1"},{"key2","value2"},{"key3","value3"}]`

`List<JSONObject>` gives me the flexibility of looping through using for-each loop, while `JSONArray` will give `JSONException` when using `getJSONObject` method. Which is the better method here?

Answer (score 5):

They are almost same apart from one major difference. If you look close at source code, `JsonArray` implements `List`.

So it is already a type of `List`

```
public interface JsonArray
extends JsonStructure, List<JsonValue>
```

However the major difference is that, JsonArray is `immutable`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html

> JsonArray represents an immutable JSON array (an ordered sequence of zero or more values). It also provides an unmodifiable list view of the values in the array.

Choose carefully if you want to have an immutable container of Json, use JsonArray.